# Azure insert does not add new properties of an entity (Java)

Tags: java, azure

I have a database with Azure Table Storage where I store entities with a variety of properties and all has been working well. However, when I try to add a new property, it does not get stored at all. My InsertEntity code looks like this:

```
LunchDateEntity entity = new LunchDateEntity(ID);
try{

AppStorage storage = new AppStorage(TABLENAME);
entity.setProperty1(prop1)
entity.setProperty2(prop2)
entity.setProperty3(prop3)

entity.setNewProperty(newProp)

TableOperation operation = TableOperation.insert(entity);
m_table.execute(operation);
} 
catch(...) {...}
```

Prop 1,2,3 which are entities I have had since before are added in the Table Storage, however, newProp does not show att all in the Table Storage.

I have tried to hardcode the property when constructing the entity, but to no avail.

My Entity class looks as:

```
public class myEntity extends TableServiceEntity {
public static final String TABLENAME = "myTable";
public static final String PARTITION_KEY = "part1";

public String m_prop1 = "";
public String m_prop2 = "";
public String m_prop3 = "";
public String m_newProp = "";

public myEntity() {
 this.partitionKey = PARTITION_KEY;
} 

public void setProp1(String prop1) {
  m_prop1 = prop1;
}

public String getProp1() {
 return m_prop1;
}

public void setNewProp(String newProp) {
 m_newProp = newProp;
}
```

And so on and so forth for all properties. They all look alike.

Have I misunderstood how the insert function works? Is there any ideas why this does not work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue on my side.Could you use Fiddler to catch the insert request body to see the your entity?

Comment: Which table storage version you are using? The new property doesn't shows or just be null value?

Comment: That is strange... My code lies within a function app and I insert entities with HTTP POST requests. If I stringify the entity and return it, the newProp shows up in the response in Postman. The problem seems to me to lie in the insert function. I will try updating TableStorage to 1.4.2 and see what happens.

Comment: sure, i also will try insert entity in the azure http trigger function.

Comment: The update did not make any difference. The value is not null, the table has no column at all for that property.   

Edit: I have setters and getters for all properties but the newProp set/get is copy+paste from earlier props that do work.

Comment: I may have misled you, when I stringify the entry BEFORE the insert the newProp exists, when I stringify it AFTER the insert the newProp is empty. But in Table Storage there is no newProp column.

Comment: I cannot talk there due to low reputation, sorry... I can add my class in the OP.

Comment: You could debug your azure function locally? To locate when the new property setting gone.

Comment: Yes it is exactly where I use the insert() function.

Comment: I'm testing on my side in azure function with your code,any progress will be posted here.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941958/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-an-existing-azure-table-storage

Which implies that what I am doing should work... If I add another property it should be added as a column in the Table Storage.

Comment: I have also searched the case, however i think it is not suitable for you,what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, I think it's because of the name rule. I tested add newProp or newProp1 field, as same as your solution. The new property didn't show up.

Then I tried add name, tel or even oldProp, everything worked.

Function code:

```
@FunctionName("addentity")
    public String addentity(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {"get", "post"}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) String req,
                            ExecutionContext context) {

        String storageConnectionString =
                "***";
        String jsonStr = "insert failed";

        try {
            // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
                    CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

            // Create the table client.
            CloudTableClient tableClient =
                    storageAccount.createCloudTableClient();

            // Create a cloud table object for the table.
            CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.getTableReference("test");

            // Create a new customer entity.
            myEntity entity = new myEntity("jay1","gong");
            //entity.setProp1("a");
            entity.setNewProp("new");
            entity.setOldProp("old");
            //entity.setNewProp1("new1");
            //entity.setName("kkkkk");

            // Create an operation to add the new customer to the people table.
            TableOperation insertEntity =
                    TableOperation.insert(entity);

            // Submit the operation to the table service.
            cloudTable.execute(insertEntity);

            jsonStr = entity.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Output the stack trace.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return jsonStr;
    }
```

My entity:

```
package com.fabrikam.functions;

import com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceEntity;

public class myEntity extends TableServiceEntity {

    public String m_prop1 = "";
    public String m_newProp = "";
    public String m_newProp1 = "";

    public String name = "";
    public String oldProp = "";

    public myEntity(String lastName, String firstName) {
        this.partitionKey = lastName;
        this.rowKey = firstName;
    }

    public void setProp1(String prop1) {
        m_prop1 = prop1;
    }

    public String getProp1() {
        return m_prop1;
    }


    public String getNewProp(String newProp) {
        return m_newProp;
    }

    public String getNewProp1(String newProp1) {
        return m_newProp1;
    }


    public void setNewProp(String newProp) {
        m_newProp = newProp;
    }

    public void setNewProp1(String newProp1) {
        m_newProp1 = newProp1;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOldProp() {
        return oldProp;
    }

    public void setOldProp(String oldProp) {
        this.oldProp = oldProp;
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

I think something like `'newProp'` has been preserved by Azure Table Storage, you could adjust name rule then everything will be fine.

---

I do further test:

[image]

---

Just for summary, finally, it's all about the wrong format of my getters and setters. We need to check the object definition.

Comment: This is too kind. I have tried different names, like "testString" and "details" but they don't show. I can try Name, since that worked for you.

Comment: @EAAL Ok, tried to recreate a table storage to test again.Or clean up everything.

Comment: I have tried on a different table but with the same result... I noticed something extremely strange now. My entity class and the addEntity class are of course different files. When I change the function name setProp1 to something like setP1 the table does not insert that value, it gets set to null. Even though the only thing I did was change the function name. I do not know why that is.

Comment: @EAAL I did further test and it works for me. Maybe the change file isn't effective for you?

Comment: @EAAL Maybe try to paste my working code to test?not modify your own code.

Comment: Hello, no I have no progress. I have noticed some real weird peculiarities though. If I rename (ONLY rename) some set-functions, like setProp1 then that will not insert in the table either. Something is fishy..

Comment: I found the problem! I had the wrong format of my getters and setters, and on one prop I forgot the setter. You are a hero for helping me though, thank you very much.